# Task Parelle Library with C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, task-parallel-library

I am new to the concept of Task Parallel Library in dot net. Is it possible to use Task parallel library and its parallelism concepts with C++/CLI code? I am trying to introduce parallelism into my object Factory classes to speed up processes.

Any pointers or code snippets will help me immensely.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Using TPL is only bearable in a language that supports lambda expressions.  C++/CLI does not.  It isn't impossible to write TPL code without it, it is just very little fun.  And ultimately just not necessary, take advantage of C++/CLI's ability to easily call C# code.  So just write your TPL code in C#.  Or use the native C++ TPL support, use the `<concrt.h> header.